# Which one is correct and why?

Tags: grammar, writing-style, locative-inversion

Across the Chesapeake Bay from the rest of the state ........ , whose farms produce beans, tomatoes, and other garden vegetables.

A. there lies Maryland's Eastern Shore

B. lies Maryland's Eastern Shore

C. Maryland's Eastern Shore lies there

D. Maryland's Eastern Shore lies

My teacher has already said that the correct choice is B.

What is your opinion?

PLease elaborate your explanations. I would like a REASON not just a YES or NO.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

> **A.** Across the Chesapeake Bay from the rest of the state, there lies
>   Maryland's Eastern Shore, whose farms produce beans, tomatoes, and
>   other garden vegetables.

This uses 'existential there' whose use is not ungrammatical here, but which does give a rather archaic flavour in this instance.

**B** is correct (if one accepts the capitalisation), and the inversion after the adverbial is usually preferred.

**C** would need a fair overhaul:

> Across the Chesapeake Bay from the rest of the state – Maryland's
>   Eastern Shore lies there. The farms of that area  produce beans,
>   tomatoes, and other garden vegetables.

Notice that this 'there' is the locative one. This version sounds rather poetical.

**D** probably requires a slight re-ordering or (better) re-structuring:

> Across the Chesapeake Bay from the rest of the state, Maryland's
>   Eastern Shore, whose farms produce beans, tomatoes, and other garden
>   vegetables, lies.
>
> Across the Chesapeake Bay from the rest of the state, Maryland's
>   Eastern Shore lies. Its farms produce beans, tomatoes, and other
>   garden vegetables.

Comment: I'll agree that A is not ungrammatical but that it does sound rather odd. I actually don't think it's archaic, just unusual.

Comment: For all the Ngrams I've checked for 'X there lies' v 'X lies', (eg [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hills+there+lies%2C+hills+lies&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chills%20there%20lies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chills%20lies%3B%2Cc0) ) (where X = hills, sea, river, mountain ...) there are just blips for 'X there lies' in the past (eg 1810, 1880 here).

Comment: "If one accepts the capitalisation" - that's standard: ["Eastern Shore" is a formal name for the region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Shore_of_Maryland).

Comment: @Peter: I don't think the basic usage is at all "unusual". If you're giving someone directions, for example, you might say *" A few hundred yards up this road is a supermarket. Across the road **there's** a narrow alley. The place you're looking for is just up that alley on the left"*. The word "there" might be superfluous, but it's often included in such contexts.

Comment: @FF I think it's 'there lies' that I find evocative of – well, little yellow idols, coral cays, and LJS's treasure.

Answer (score 1):

A is grammatical. *There*, in the OED’s words, is ‘used unemphatically to introduce a sentence or clause in which, for the sake of emphasis or preparing the hearer, the verb comes before its subject’.

B dispenses with *there*, but it is equally grammatical. *Maryland's Eastern Shore* is the subject and *lies* is the verb.

C is ungrammatical. That is because *there*, when it is used as in A, must normally precede the verb.

D is just about grammatical, but is unsatisfactory, because it separates the modifying relative clause (*whose farms . . .*) from its antecedent.

Comment: +1, for there are at least two threads on this issue, and finally someone mentions that #A is grammatical and fine. :)

Comment: Though, I'd probably be thinking that "there" was indicating the location *"Across the Chesapeake Bay from the rest of the state"*.

Comment: But, who knows the reason why D is incorrect?

Comment: I didn’t say it was incorrect. It’s not an effective sentence because the antecedent of _whose_ is not immediately clear to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

**B** is the correct answer. Why?

The correct way to form a sentence (with some exceptions) is to use the following format:

(Adjective +) Pronoun + (Adjective +) Verb + (Adjective +) noun + extra fluff.